# using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSession Many messages Complete(), Abort(), Etc

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I am having a problem closing out the MessageSession when there are more than one messages to be received... I wait for all of the sequence to come in and then I try and "Complete()" all of the messages in the session. I have tried lots of different ways from iterating through the messages received and "Complete()"-ing them, "Close()"-ing the session, "Completing()"-ing the session, I cannot find the winning formula for the life of me. Microsoft's documentation is not very helpful either. It certainly doesn't provide a decent example. The following is the code as I have it in it's most recent iteration

public   QueueMessageBody ReceiveResponse(string sessionId)
        {

```
        try
        {
            MessagingFactory _messagingFactory;
            _messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

            var receiver = _messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(ResponseQueue, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
            var messageBodyStream = new MemoryStream();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for new message");
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    var receiverSession = receiver.AcceptMessageSession(sessionId);
                    messageBodyStream = new MemoryStream();

                    var keepPolling = true;
                    var isFirstMessage = true;
                    var expectedNoMessages = 0;
                    BrokeredMessage[] messages = null;
                    var messagesReceived = 0;
                    while (keepPolling)
                    {
                        var message = receiverSession.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                        if (message == null)
                            continue;

                        if (isFirstMessage)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Receiving first message");
                            expectedNoMessages = (int)message.Properties["TotalMessages"];
                            messages = new BrokeredMessage[expectedNoMessages];
                            isFirstMessage = false;
                        }

                        var messageNo = (int)message.Properties["MessageNo"];
                        var messageIndex = messageNo - 1;
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Receiving message {0}", messageNo));
                        messages[messageIndex] = message;
                        messagesReceived++;

                        if (messagesReceived == expectedNoMessages)
                            keepPolling = false;
                    }





                    //Rebuild Object
                    var messageBodyBuilder = new ChunkedMessageBuilder().ReconstructMessageBody(messages);
                    var o = SerializationHelper.Deserialize<QueueMessageBody>(messageBodyBuilder);

                    var completeTasks = new List<Task>();
                    if (messages.Count()< 3)
                    {
                        foreach (var message in messages)
                            completeTasks.Add(receiverSession.CompleteAsync(message.LockToken));
                        Task.WaitAll(completeTasks.ToArray());
                    }else
                    {
                        receiverSession.Close();
                    }


                    return o;


                }
            }



        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }

    }


  public   QueueMessageBody ReceiveResponse(string sessionId)
    {

        try
        {
            MessagingFactory _messagingFactory;
            _messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

            var receiver = _messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(ResponseQueue, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
            var messageBodyStream = new MemoryStream();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for new message");
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    var receiverSession = receiver.AcceptMessageSession(sessionId);
                    messageBodyStream = new MemoryStream();

                    var keepPolling = true;
                    var isFirstMessage = true;
                    var expectedNoMessages = 0;
                    BrokeredMessage[] messages = null;
                    var messagesReceived = 0;
                    while (keepPolling)
                    {
                        var message = receiverSession.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                        if (message == null)
                            continue;

                        if (isFirstMessage)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Receiving first message");
                            expectedNoMessages = (int)message.Properties["TotalMessages"];
                            messages = new BrokeredMessage[expectedNoMessages];
                            isFirstMessage = false;
                        }

                        var messageNo = (int)message.Properties["MessageNo"];
                        var messageIndex = messageNo - 1;
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Receiving message {0}", messageNo));
                        messages[messageIndex] = message;
                        messagesReceived++;

                        if (messagesReceived == expectedNoMessages)
                            keepPolling = false;
                    }





                    //Rebuild Object
                    var messageBodyBuilder = new ChunkedMessageBuilder().ReconstructMessageBody(messages);
                    var o = SerializationHelper.Deserialize<QueueMessageBody>(messageBodyBuilder);

                    var completeTasks = new List<Task>();
                    if (messages.Count()< 3)
                    {
                        foreach (var message in messages)
                            completeTasks.Add(receiverSession.CompleteAsync(message.LockToken));
                        Task.WaitAll(completeTasks.ToArray());
                    }else
                    {
                        receiverSession.Close();
                    }


                    return o;


                }
            }



        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

And the queue is configured as follows.

[image: The Queue configuration.]

I am able to receive the messages and complete the workflow on them, the problem is they just stay there in the queue. I cannot complete them at

Comment: What is the purpose of the TransactionScope? Why do you not Complete() it?

Comment: I was mostly following the pattern outlined here by this fellow:
http://microsoftintegration.guru/2014/12/23/azure-service-bus-larger-messages/
The transactionscope was apart of his session example. I will try it without and see the result, Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked this: http://www.cloudcasts.net/devguide/Default.aspx?id=13033

Comment: You were correct, the transaction scope was causing the failure. Thanks so much! What a headache!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the issue was perhaps the fact that the transaction was never completed. Removing the TransactionScope got rid of the issue.

Comment: Thanks again! Sometimes, a simple answer is not so simple. :/